# cisco 2811 router serial int config

Tags: cisco, router

I use cisco 2811 router when I try to config s0/0/0 serial interface using `(config)#int serial 0/0/0`commond it says "%Invalid interface type and number" what's wrong with this commond?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The router does not think it has an interface with that name run **show ip int brief** to get a list of interfaces present in the router

This may be of help.

Interface and Line Numbers in Cisco 1800, 2800 and 3800 Series Routers

www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/routers/ps282/products_tech_note09186a008035b051.shtml